# How to decompress a partial chunked gzip data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, gzip, aiohttp

In search of a solution of similar [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676116/) but in python using `gzip` or `zlib`.
This SO question [How to inflate a partial zlib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620374/) does not work (see the first test case)
Not a duplicate of [Unzipping part of a .gz file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732709/), that is not working (and outdated)
These two: [Unzip part of a file using python gzip module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726696/) and [Is it possible to figure how to decompress a file, knowing its first bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70979504/) are close to this question (though different) but unfortunately first one doesn't have a working solution and the second one doesn't have any answers at all...

I am iterating over a chunked pieces of gzip bytes received from a remote server, it looks something like this :

```py
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(LINK) as response:
            with open(FILE, "wb") as f:
                async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(chunk_size):
                    # Write the decompressed chunk
                    # to `f`
                    ...
```

The following are the non-working solutions :
1)

```py
    decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(LINK) as response:
            with open(FILE, "wb") as f:
                async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(chunk_size):
                    # Write the decompressed chunk
                    r = decompressor.decompress(chunk, chunk_size)
                    # for some reason `r` is always empty
                    # writing to `f` is pointless
                    print(f"{len(chunk) = }, {r = }, {len(r) = }")
```

And here, the `r` seems to be empty.
stdout :

```
len(chunk) = 64, r = b'', len(r) = 0
len(chunk) = 64, r = b'', len(r) = 0
len(chunk) = 64, r = b'', len(r) = 0
len(chunk) = 64, r = b'', len(r) = 0
len(chunk) = 64, r = b'', len(r) = 0
len(chunk) = 64, r = b'', len(r) = 0
...
```

2)
doing `zlib.decompress(...)` doesn't seem to work either on partial data

```py
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(LINK) as response:
            with open(DIR, "wb") as f:
                async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(chunk_size):
                    f.write(zlib.decompress(chunk))
```

This raises :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lumin\Desktop\rplace\get_data.py", line 54, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\lumin\Desktop\rplace\get_data.py", line 51, in main
    await download_content(0)
  File "c:\Users\lumin\Desktop\rplace\get_data.py", line 47, in download_content
    f.write(zlib.decompress(chunk))
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

3)
Passing in `gzip.decompress(chunk)` like this :

```py
            with open(DIR, "wb") as f:
                async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(chunk_size):
                    f.write(gzip.decompress(chunk))
```

Causes this :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lumin\Desktop\rplace\get_data.py", line 54, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\lumin\Desktop\rplace\get_data.py", line 51, in main
    await download_content(0)
  File "c:\Users\lumin\Desktop\rplace\get_data.py", line 47, in download_content
    f.write(gzip.decompress(chunk))
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\gzip.py", line 557, in decompress
    return f.read()
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\gzip.py", line 301, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\_compression.py", line 118, in readall
    while data := self.read(sys.maxsize):
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\gzip.py", line 479, in read
    self._read_eof()
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\gzip.py", line 523, in _read_eof
    crc32, isize = struct.unpack("<II", self._read_exact(8))
  File "C:\Users\lumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\gzip.py", line 425, in _read_exact
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

The full code looks something like this :

```py
from typing import Final
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import os


if os.name == "nt":
    # Prevent noisy exit on Windows
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())


async def download_content(
    number: int, *, directory: str | None = None, chunk_size: int = 64
) -> None:
    """
    Download the content of a archived canvas history file.
    And extracts it immediately.

    Args:
        number: The number associated with the archive.
        directory: The directory to extract the file to, defaults to root.
        chunk_size: The size of the chunks to download and extract, defaults to 64.

    Raises:
        TypeError: Argument got invalid type.
        ValueError: number wasn't between 0 and 77.
    """
    if not isinstance(number, int):
        raise TypeError(f"'number' must be of type 'int' got {type(number)}")
    if not isinstance(directory, str) and directory is not None:
        raise TypeError(f"'directory' must be of type 'str' got {type(directory)}")
    if not isinstance(chunk_size, int):
        raise TypeError(f"'chunk_size' must be of type 'int' got {type(chunk_size)}")
    if 0 > number > 77:
        raise ValueError(f"'number' must be between 0 and 77 got {number}")

    LINK: Final[str] = "https://placedata.reddit.com/data/canvas-history/2022_place_canvas_history-"
    FILE_LOCATION: Final[str] = f"{'0' * (12 - len(str(number)))}{number}.csv.gzip"
    DIR: Final[str] = directory if directory is not None else "./"

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(LINK + FILE_LOCATION) as response:
            with open(DIR + FILE_LOCATION[:-5], "wb") as f:
                async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(chunk_size):
                    # Write the decompressed chunk to the file
                    ...


async def main():
    await download_content(0)


asyncio.run(main())
```

TLDR: We have received an `gzip` file and are iterating over the chunks, we are interested in decompressing these said partial data and writing them to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the second argument of `decompress()` means what you think it means. It is not the length of the input (which is already available from the byte array itself), but rather a constraint on the length of the decompressed data returned. You should not even specify it, allowing `decompress()` to return all of the decompressed data it has so far.

The code below works for me. I used `split -b 64` to split a gzip file into 64-byte chunks `xaa`, `xab`, etc., and then ran the command below with the arguments `x??` to provide those chunks in order. The combined decompressed result was correctly written to stdout.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import zlib
gz = zlib.decompressobj(31)
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(arg, "rb") as f:
        chunk = f.read()
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(gz.decompress(chunk))
sys.stdout.buffer.write(gz.flush())
```

(The final flush isn't really needed, as the last `decompress()` will return all of the decompressed data from the last chunk. I include it for completeness to effectively close the decompression object and release any resources it has sequestered.)